# Does roasting coffee in small batches produce more/better flavor?

Tags: nutrition

On a Caribou coffee cup I got today the sleeve says

> Roasted in small batches for larger-than-life flavor.

Is there any evidence that roasting coffee in small batches produces more (or "better") flavor?

Comment: The specific question is answerable, but the overall claim is too broad to be addressed reasonably.  Also, "perceived" can be a heck of a weasel word here, and not really helpful.  Perception can be changed by marketing, after all.

Comment: @BenBarden I was hoping that there may have been a blind study of some sort.  Also, I was originally thinking of just coffee roasting and then thought broadening it might allow for more wiggle room if coffee roasting specifically wasn't tested but other things were.  Would it be helpful (in terms of making this more answerable) to limit the question to just coffee roasting?

Comment: it would actually probably be best to target some specific claim that a specific (preferably large) organization was making about their product, and include a direct quote.  Direct quotes that one can disprove or confirm are always helpful.

Comment: @BenBarden I've edit my question to hopefully bring it more into the realm of what you're saying.  Let me know if there's anything else I can improve or if this is maybe just too opinion-based a topic to put together a good question for on this site.

Comment: @Peter You have a point although I'm partially wondering if maybe differences in roaster size may produce different effects in coffee which may in turn at least produce a different effect which some people may view as positive. Something like that would presumably also come with chemical differences that may be measurable.  I agree that it's logical that there would be variance with different methods/devices but I don't know what those details would be which is a part of why I'm asking the question.

Comment: In the coffee example it's not about producing "better" batches. It's about detecting, throwing out, and being able to afford throwing out the bad batches. Of course you can have good quality control with big batches, and you can decide to have no quality control with small batches. But I like our edit, someone with industry experience might be able to write a good answer now.

Comment: another useful reference for a similar claim: https://utopiancoffee.com/faq/what-is-small-batch-roasting/ - they're saying that the small batches allow for both obsessive quality control, and more flexibility to finesse things during the roasting process.  I don't know if it's accurate, but it at least sounds plausible.

Comment: While this is a fascinating question; it just doesn't seem suitable for skeptics.  It's hard to believe there is a "real" answer as everything involved is so subjective.  For example, consider other food and cuisine questions such as "Should cheese be at room temperature?"  "Are single-clos wines actually better?" "Is filet-mignon actually better than T-bone?" and so on.

Comment: I can easily answer this, but not with an official answer. It's not just a matter of coffee: small batches are often better in cooking things, fir the simple reason that they fit better in the pan and can be cooked more uniformly. Just to make a simple example...imagine having a barbecue and, to be able to cook more things at the same time, pile things on it in two or three layers: it's obvious that even if you try to turn things a lot, you'll end up with some things better cooked and some others badly cooked. That's the reason we put few things on the bbq and pay a lot of attention to them

Comment: The same goes for coffee, and as I said for lot of other things: you want to cook everything for the better, so you try to have a single layer over the cooking surface to have the best possible control of the process and the most uniform roasting. No matter how many times you turn and shake the container, if you roast 30 kilos of coffee at the time you'll end up using a big container and not all the beans will roast the same. You'll either burn some of them to allow the rest to be decently roasted, or you'll stop as soon as the average are roasted and then the rest will still be "fresh"

Comment: Note: "opinion-based" answers are not allowed here.  Not even your own personal taste tests.

Comment: There's a cooking stack. Motion to move this there.

Comment: Advertizing is mostly not intended to be taken seriously. I vote to close this unless there is a notable source that is not an advert.

Comment: Not enough for an answer but roasting coffee is very closely tied to the moisture in the beans and how fast that moisture is lost in the roasting process. There is a moment where the coffee with *crack* (almost like popcorn) which is used to gauge progress in roasting.  Using smaller batches allows for more homogeneity in the batch where more of the beans crack at the same time.

Comment: I have no doubt that this is true, but as others have noted, this is highly subjective.    In my, experience this is entirely due to the size rather than due to any improved quality control in the roasting process.  Simply put, a smaller batch is less likely to become stale prior to becoming consumed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably refers to roasting in traditional drum roasters in batches.

There are basically two methods of roasting employed by commercial coffee roasters.

1. **Drum roasting**. Basically a Drum is heated from below and revolted to stir and mix the beans to heat them evenly. This takes about 15-20 minutes, depending on the desired darkness of the roast.
2. **Hot Air roasting**. Here the beans are heated by hot air and reach target temperature much quicker. This can be implemented in a continuous process for industrial scale production. Roasting times go from 3-6 minutes.

Both methods have their advantages and disadvantages. Most obvious is the different roasting time, which advocates of the drum-roasting claim to give the chemical processes in the beans more time to develop the flavor.

From a roasters perspective:

- Neutral [reference](https://legacy.sweetmarias.com/library/tinyjoy/aug-sept-2003-drum-roasting-vs-air-roasting)
- Pro Small batch [drum roasting](https://beans.at/en/kaffeewissen/kaffeeroestung/kaffeeroestvorgang)
- Pro [hot-air roasting](http://www.global-coffee.ca/air-roasting-vs-drum-roasting/)